# Salesforce Apex Test Class Failing on saving of an account

Tags: testing, salesforce, visualforce, apex

having a little trouble figuring out why my test class is returning `System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]`

I have required field `Name` on the Account object in SFDC, but Since I'm mocking the Account with a Name attribute shouldn't my test class save function work?

Below is my Apex Class 
public with sharing class QuoteAccountController {

```
// Define VariableType and VariableName
public ApexPages.StandardController standardContactController;
public Account Account{get;set;}
public Contact Contact{get;set;}
public Account selectedAccount{get;set;}
public Boolean displayProjectInformation{get;set;}
public Boolean projectNameError{get;set;}
public Boolean projectValidationsPassed{get;set;}

//Page Constructor/Initializer
public QuoteAccountController(ApexPages.StandardController StandardController) {
    Account = new Account();    
    Contact = new Contact();
    displayProjectInformation = true;
    projectNameError = false;
    projectValidationsPassed = true;
}

public pageReference save() {
    projectValidations();
    if (projectValidationsPassed) {
        upsert Account;
        Contact.accountId = Account.id;
        upsert Contact;
        Contact = new Contact();
        Account = new Account();
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
        return null;
     } else {
         return null;
     }
}

public void projectValidations(){
    if (Account.Subscription_Type__c == 'Project' && String.isBlank(Account.Project_Name__c)) {
        projectValidationsPassed = false;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Project Name is required field'));
    } else if (Account.Subscription_Type__c == 'Project' && String.isBlank(Account.Project_Type__c)) {
        projectValidationsPassed = false;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Project Type is required field'));
    } else if (Account.Subscription_Type__c == 'Project' && Account.Project_Start_Date__c == null) {
        projectValidationsPassed = false;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Project Start Date is required field'));
    } else if (Account.Subscription_Type__c == 'Project' && Account.Project_End_Date__c == null){
        projectValidationsPassed = false;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Project End Date is required field'));
    } else {
        projectValidationsPassed = true;
    }
}
```

Below is my Apex Test Class

```
@isTest
public class QuoteAccountControllerTest {
 private static testmethod void testSave() {
     Quote quote = new Quote();
     Account testAcc = new Account();
     Contact con = new Contact();
     ApexPages.StandardController stdCont = new ApexPages.StandardController(testAcc);
     QuoteAccountController quoteAccCont = new QuoteAccountController(stdCont);
     PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/zqu_QuoteAccount?quoteType=Subscription&stepNumber=1');
     Test.setCurrentPage(page);

     testAcc.Project_Name__c = 'Project Name';
     testAcc.Name = 'Test Account';
     testAcc.Project_Start_Date__c = Date.today();
     testAcc.Project_End_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(2);
     testAcc.Project_Type__c =  'Convention Center';
     testAcc.Region__c = 'US';
     testAcc.Subscription_Type__c = 'User';

     Test.startTest();
     quoteAccCont.save();
     Test.stopTest();
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: Error message below.

```
System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]
```

Comment: Please put the complete error with line nos.

Comment: @AjaySainy added error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much background in Salesforce but I believe that you need to insert the objects that you are creating with new before Test.startTest();

If this fails too, try to use System.debug() in your Apex Test class and use the Salesforce developer console and their logs to follow your error. Maybe this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jordi. I'm trying to test the creation of an Account the first time, which would be insert in this case so I don't think I should insert then run #save

Comment: You're welcome. In my case, I've done only 3 test classes with some help of my workmates. 

Have you tried to get some accounts of your org with a query? 

This could be another way to cover your class, and you will avoid missing field problems . Then, as soon as you got it, you should be able to upsert it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `upsert` an account. Upsert(Update/Insert) call would look for `Id` in the account you are upserting. If `Id` is found `Upsert` would work fine else it would `Insert`. So in your case it is trying to insert not update. That is why `Name` is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my request Ajay. In my test class I provide a Name attribute to the Account I'm trying to save so shouldn't the required field pass? 

    testAcc.Name = 'Test Account';

Comment: Matt, Have you tried calling save method. I hope it will still throw the error. Issue is not in test class. As you are creating data in your actual class and not querying data, it will not refer to record you create in test class.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out solution. Need to assign the Account and Contact to the Controller. See modified code below.

```
@isTest
public class QuoteAccountControllerTest {
 private static testmethod void testSave() {
 Quote quote = new Quote();
 ApexPages.StandardController stdCont = new ApexPages.StandardController(testAcc);
 QuoteAccountController quoteAccCont = new QuoteAccountController(stdCont);
 quoteAccCont.Account = new Account(ATTRIBUTES_HERE);
 quoteAccCont.Contact = new Contact(ATTRIBUTES_HERE
 PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/zqu_QuoteAccount?quoteType=Subscription&stepNumber=1');
 Test.setCurrentPage(page);

 Test.startTest();
 quoteAccCont.save();
 Test.stopTest();
 }
}
```